# Flattening a list of object properties

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functional-programming, reduce

I'm finding it difficult to write this code in a functional style after years of working with an imperative mindset.

Given an input like:

```
[{'id': 'foo', frames: ['bar', 'baz']}, {'id': 'two', frames: ['three', 'four']}]
```

The output should be:

```
[ { foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }, { two: 'three' }, { two: 'four' } ]
```

How would one write this in a functional style in javascript?

Comment: i have this[ { foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' } { two: 'three' }, { two: 'four' } ] wanted to convert to this [ { foo: 'bar' ,  foo: 'baz' , two: 'three' , two: 'four' } ] .any pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's create a function which given an object returns an array of frames:

```
function toFrames(obj) {
    var id = obj.id;

    return obj.frames.map(function (frame) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[id] = frame;
        return obj;
    });
}
```

Next we create a `concat` function:

```
function concat(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
}
```

Finally we do the transformation:

```
var input = [{
    id: "foo",
    frames: ["bar", "baz"]
}, {
    id: "two",
    frames: ["three", "four"]
}];

var output = input.map(toFrames).reduce(concat);
```

See the demo for yourself:

```js
var input = [{
    id: "foo",
    frames: ["bar", "baz"]
}, {
    id: "two",
    frames: ["three", "four"]
}];

var output = input.map(toFrames).reduce(concat);

alert(JSON.stringify(output, null, 4));

function toFrames(obj) {
    var id = obj.id;

    return obj.frames.map(function (frame) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[id] = frame;
        return obj;
    });
}

function concat(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
}
```

Isn't functional programming fun?

---

An explanation:

1. The `toFrames` function takes a object (for example `{ id: "foo", frames: ["bar", "baz"] }`) and returns the list of frame objects (i.e. `[{ foo: "bar" }, { foo: "baz" }]`).
2. The `concat` function just concatenates two arrays. The `.reduce(concat)` method call flatttens arrays like `[[a,b],[c,d]]` to `[a,b,c,d]`.
3. Given an input list of objects, we first convert each object into a list of frames, resulting in a list of list of frame objects.
4. We then flatten the nested list to produce the desired output.

Simple.

Comment: It's so simple now I look at it, I must practice this stuff more. Thanks!

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way supposing `arr` is the input

```
result = []; // array
arr.forEach(function(o) { // go through elements
    for (var i = 0; i < o.frames.length; i++) { // make a since we need to get two objs per element
        var obj = {}; // an object which will be over written for every iteration
        obj[o.id] = o.frames[i]; // set property name and value
        result.push(obj); // finally push it in the array
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of for each, but this is quite a simple solution!

Comment: This is incorrect, this will output only the first value in each frames list.

Comment: Your style of programming is not very functional. All you've done is replaced a `for` loop with a `forEach`. It still looks very procedural to me.

Comment: @AaditMShah it does its work in less code, what's procedural and functional?? It is more concise way rather than big blocks of code. It can be easily converted into a function

Comment: Functional programming not only means programming with first class functions but also programming without side effects. Although you have used higher-order functions in your program, you still do have side effects. Pushing elements to an array is a side effect. I cannot explain functional programming in one comment. It's best if you learn a pure functional programming language like Haskell yourself. That way you will better understand what's functional programming: http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Comment: @AaditMShah well, I'm currently learning Golang, will learn Haskell too. BTW, I don't see any side-effects in pushing

Comment: Pushing to an array mutates the array. For example, suppose we have an array `var a = [1,2,3]` and I do `a.push(4)`. I have mutated the array. It now contains `[1,2,3,4]`. Functional programmers believe that mutation is bad because it adds complexity to the program (read the famous research paper [Out of the Tar Pit](https://github.com/papers-we-love/papers-we-love/blob/master/design/out-of-the-tar-pit.pdf)). Hence most data structures in FP languages are immutable. For example lists are immutable. You can't push to a list. However you can create a new list with a new element from an old list.